# How can I raise a matrix to a power with multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, matrix, stdthread

I am trying to raise a matrix to a power with multiple threads, but I am not very good with threads. Also I enter the number of threads from keyboard and that number is in range [1, matrix height], then I do the following:

```
unsigned period = ceil((double)A.getHeight() / threadNum);
unsigned prev = 0, next = period;
for (unsigned i(0); i < threadNum; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back(&power<long long>, std::ref(result), std::ref(A), std::ref(B), prev, next, p);

        if (next + period > A.getHeight()) {
            prev = next;
            next = A.getHeight();
        }
        else {
            prev = next;
            next += period;
        }
    }
```

It was easy for me to multiply one matrix by another with multiple threads, but here the problem is that once 1 step is done, for example I need to raise A to the power of 3, A^2 would be that one step, after that step I have to wait for all the threads to finish up, before moving on to doing A^2*A. How can I make my threads wait for that? I'm using std::thread's.

***After the first reply was posted I realized that I forgot to mention that I want to create those threads only once, and not recreate them for each multiplication step.***

Comment: As an aside, linear multiplication will be needlessly inefficient.  Try calculating `A^7` = `A * A^2 * A^4`, where `A^4 = A^2^2`.  This requires 4 multiplications instead of 7 the naive way.  Keep on squaring on one hand, then multiply the square into your result based off the bits of the exponent, stopping the squaring when done.

Comment: I know all that, however, this is more of a thread question, not matrix, thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to create the threads only once?

Comment: @Hurkyl, because I can, lol.

Comment: @Hurkyl creating a thread is not that cheap.

Comment: @Yakk: Cheap is relative; if each task is enough work, the thread startup cost doesn't matter. And even if it is relevant, the benefit of eliminating it still might not be enough to be worth the cost of designing, implementing, and maintaining a more complicated solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Algorithm would be something like this:

1. Split the matrix in N parts for N threads.
2. Each thread calculates the necessary resulting sub matrix for a single multiplication.
3. Then it increments an atomic `threads_finished` counter using `fetch_add` and waits on a shared condition variable.
4. Last thread that finishes (fetch_add()+1 == thread count), notifies all threads, that they can now continue processing.
5. Profit.

Edit:
Here is and example how to stop threads:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>

void sync_threads(std::condition_variable & cv, std::mutex & mut, std::vector<int> & threads, const int idx) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
    threads[idx] = 1; 
    if(std::find(threads.begin(),threads.end(),0) == threads.end()) {
        for(auto & i: threads)
            i = 0;
        cv.notify_all();
    } else {
        while(threads[idx])
            cv.wait(lock);
    }
}

int main(){

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    std::mutex mut;
    std::condition_variable cv;

    int max_threads = 10;
    std::vector<int> thread_wait(max_threads,0);

    for(int i = 0; i < max_threads; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back([&,i](){
                std::cout << "Thread "+ std::to_string(i)+" started\n";
                sync_threads(cv,mut,thread_wait,i);
                std::cout << "Continuing thread " + std::to_string(i) + "\n";
                sync_threads(cv,mut,thread_wait,i);
                std::cout << "Continuing thread for second time " + std::to_string(i) + "\n";

            });
    }

    for(auto & i: threads)
        i.join();
}
```

The interesting part is here:

```
void sync_threads(std::condition_variable & cv, std::mutex & mut, std::vector<int> & threads, const int idx) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut); // Lock because we want to modify cv
    threads[idx] = 1; // Set my idx to 1, so we know we are sleeping
    if(std::find(threads.begin(),threads.end(),0) == threads.end()) {
        // I'm the last thread, wake up everyone
        for(auto & i: threads)
            i = 0;
        cv.notify_all();
    } else { //I'm not the last thread - sleep until all are finished
        while(threads[idx]) // In loop so, if we wake up unexpectedly, we go back to sleep. (Thanks for pointing that out Yakk)
            cv.wait(lock);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need an atomic for the counter. A `condition_variable` is always paired with a `mutex` that protects the condition in question, in this case the counter. Any modifications to the condition must happen while the mutex is locked, otherwise you will end up with a race condition in your program.

Comment: Can you please write this in code? I have no idea how to use all of that properly, first and second step I understand, third and fourth I'm confused, especially about the atomic counter. Don't write the entire thing, just show me how to pause the threads with that atomic counter before each multiplication step.

Comment: But this is waiting for other threads to get created and not waiting for other threads to finish their jobs.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 What do you mean - For me it first executes all "Starting thread" lines, only then executes "Continuing thread" lines and only then does the "Continuing thread for second time".

Comment: @UldisK so, wait, does cv.wait(lock) apply only to the current thread or does it also apply to a thread that's created after I have done it?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 all threads, that reach `cv.wait(lock)` will unlock lock and block until someone calls `cv.notfiy()` or `cv.notify_all()`, then they reacquire lock and continue processing.

Comment: You don't handle spurious wakeups in the above code.  `cv.wait(lock)` can wake up even if not notified.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `mass_thread_pool`:

```
// launches n threads all doing task F with an index:
template<class F>
struct mass_thread_pool {
  F f;
  std::vector< std::thread > threads;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::mutex m;
  size_t task_id = 0;
  size_t finished_count = 0;
  std::unique_ptr<std::promise<void>> task_done;
  std::atomic<bool> finished;

  void task( F f, size_t n, size_t cur_task ) {
    //std::cout << "Thread " << n << " launched" << std::endl;
    do {
      f(n);
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);

      if (finished)
        break;

      ++finished_count;
      if (finished_count == threads.size())
      {
        //std::cout << "task set finished" << std::endl;
        task_done->set_value();
        finished_count = 0;
      }
      cv.wait(lock,[&]{if (finished) return true; if (cur_task == task_id) return false; cur_task=task_id; return true;});
    } while(!finished);
    //std::cout << finished << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Thread " << n << " finished" << std::endl;
  }

  mass_thread_pool() = delete;
  mass_thread_pool(F fin):f(fin),finished(false) {}
  mass_thread_pool(mass_thread_pool&&)=delete; // address is party of identity

  std::future<void> kick( size_t n ) {
    //std::cout << "kicking " << n << " threads off.  Prior count is " << threads.size() << std::endl;
    std::future<void> r;
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
      ++task_id;
      task_done.reset( new std::promise<void>() );
      finished_count = 0;
      r = task_done->get_future();
      while (threads.size() < n) {
        size_t i = threads.size();
        threads.emplace_back( &mass_thread_pool::task, this, f, i, task_id );
      }
      //std::cout << "count is now " << threads.size() << std::endl;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
    return r;
  }
  ~mass_thread_pool() {
    //std::cout << "destroying thread pool" << std::endl;
    finished = true;
    cv.notify_all();
    for (auto&& t:threads) {
      //std::cout << "joining thread" << std::endl;
      t.join();
    }
    //std::cout << "destroyed thread pool" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

you construct it with a task, and then you `kick(77)` to launch 77 copies of that task (each with a different index).

`kick` returns a `std::future<void>`.  You *must* wait on this future for all of the tasks to be finished.

Then you can either destroy the thread pool, or call `kick(77)` again to relaunch the task.

The idea is that the function object you pass to `mass_thread_pool` has access to both your input and output data (say, the matrices you want to multiply, or pointers to them).  Each `kick` causes it to call your function once for each index.  You are in charge of turning indexes into offsets of whatever.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46d962e3278cc52c) where I use it to add 1 to an entry in another `vector`.  Between iterations, we swap vectors.  This does 2000 iterations, and launches 10 threads, and calls the lambda 20000 times.

Note the `auto&& pool = make_pool( lambda )` bit.  Use of `auto&&` is required -- as the thread pool has pointers into itself, I disabled both move and copy construct on a mass thread pool.  If you really need to pass it around, create a unique pointer to the thread pool.

I ran into some issues with `std::promise` resetting, so I wrapped it in a unique_ptr.  That may not be required.

Trace statements I used to debug it are commented out.

Calling `kick` with a different `n` may or may not work.  Definitely calling it with a smaller `n` will not work the way you expect (it will ignore the `n` in that case).

No processing is done until you call `kick`.  `kick` is short for "kick off".

...

In the case of your problem, what I'd do is make a multipier object that owns a `mass_thread_pool`.

The multiplier has a pointer to 3 matrices (`a`, `b` and `out`).  Each of the n subtasks generate some subsection of `out`.

You pass 2 matrices to the multiplier, it sets a pointer to `out` to a local matrix and `a` and `b` to the passed in matrices, does a `kick`, then a wait, then returns the local matrix.

For powers, you use the above multiplier to build a power-of-two tower, while multiply-accumulating based off the bits of the exponent into your result (again using the above multiplier).

A fancier version of the above could allow queuing up of multiplications and `std::future<Matrix>`s (and multiplications of future matrixes).

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a simple decomposition:

- matrix multiplication gets multithreaded
- matrix exponent calls the multiplication several times.

Something like that:

```
Mat multithreaded_multiply(Mat const& left, Mat const& right) {...}

Mat power(Mat const& M, int n)
{
    // Handle degenerate cases here (n = 0, 1)

    // Regular loop
    Mat intermediate = M;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) 
    {
        intermediate = multithreaded_multiply(M, intermediate);
    }
}
```

For waiting for `std::thread`, you have the [method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) `join()`.

Comment: But that means I have to recreate those threads every time in multithreaded_multiply, is it possible to create threads in main and reuse them somehow until I get the result?

Comment: In this case, dedicate each thread to compute the result along a line (or even for a given pixel), and let each thread compute the power result.

Comment: Yes, but then once again, how would my thread know that it's done one multiplication step and wait for the other threads to finish doing that same one multiplication step? That was my main question.

Comment: I've edited the code, look at the for(;;) join(); loop.

Comment: But this is power, your columns will be changed, if this is not done in sequence your results will be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Not a programming but math answer: for every square matrix there is a set of so called "eigenvalues" and "eigenvectors", so that M * E_i = lambda_i * E_i. M is the matrix, E_i is the eigenvector, lambda_i is the eigenvalue, which is just a complex number. So M^n * E_i = lambda_i^n *E_i. So you need only the nth power of a complex number instead of a matrix. The eigenvectors are orthogonal, i.e. any vector V = sum_i a_i * E_i. So M^n * V = sum_i a_i lambda^n E_i.
Depending on your problem this might speed up things significantly.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this relates to my problem.